# div tag doesnt display properly in browsers. what am i doing wrong? i know browsers render differntly but what is the solution to this?

Tags: html, css

CSS stylesheet

```
div.Header

{
   background-color:#999999;
   text-transform:capitalize;
   text-align:center;
}
div.leftdiv
{
float:left;
height:200px;
width:15%;
position:fixed;
background-color:#FFFF66;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:justify;
}

div.rightdiv
{ margin-left:15px;
margin-top:25px;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#FFFF99;
    width:50%
    height:200px;
    left: 438px;
    top: 39px;
}

div.footer
{ 
clear:both;
margin-left:20px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-right:20px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-right:10px;
border-color:#000066
border:thick;
text-align:center;
background-color:#FFCCFF;
}
```

Comment: footer div is not displaying at the bottom. Instead it is displaying above rightdiv.

Comment: then **add that to the question**. To do so just click the 'edit' link below the tags, and edit the question text to convey the problem and the actual question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review, it looks like you have some fixed position attributes that are tripping you up.  If you remove them, everything displays fine:

http://jsbin.com/emona3/3/edit

Comment: Nope...that still doesnt help.

Comment: what is the solution to different browsers rendering different content? I mean what properties should be used and not used?

Comment: That kinda depends which browsers you are targeting.  Quirksmode.org is my compatibility table of choice (http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)

Answer (score 0):

put `float:left` for footer its essential to move footer after all other div .